# How can I use a button style as a template for the other buttons?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a button with the following properties:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,593,0">
    <Button x:Name="btnToolbarClose" Content="X" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" Height="23" Width="30" Margin="0,-1,-1,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnToolbarMax"  Content="£" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-1,29,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Height="23" Width="30" />
    <Button x:Name="btnToolbarMin" Content="─" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-1,59,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Height="23" Width="30" >
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

And now I want that I don't have to insert this button style for each button, but simply use this style for the other buttons with bindings?So that I only have to write this style once and use it for the other buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to reuse styles of WPF controls is by using `ResourceDictionaries`.
[Link to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)

After adding a `ResourceDictionary` to your project, you can reference it by adding it to the start of your `XAML` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="./YourNewDictionary.xaml"/> // This points to the location of your dictionary.
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can define your custom style in your newly added `ResourceDictionary` somewhat like this:

```
<Style x:Key="YourButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    And all other customized properties....
</Style>
```

You can then reference your custom style in your control like this:

```
<Button x:Name="YourButton" Style="{StaticResource YourButtonStyle}">
```

This lets you easily create custom styles wich you can reuse throughout your project without much clutter in your XAML files.

Comment: Please also note that if you want to apply the style to _all buttons in scope_ of the resources automatically (without having to reference it each time with `StaticResource` or `DynmaicResource`), you can remove the `x:Key="YourButtonStyle"` to make it _implicit_.

Comment: Also avoid adding dictionaries to your window resources as those are created every time you instantiate a window, appropriate place for a style would be in App.xaml. Styles are applied implicitly unless those are in DataTemplates, then you need to use x:Key.